# Facebook Graph API: get all public photos by a specific location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't think it's possible but maybe I'm missing something.

I would like to get all public photos attached to a specific location.

I tried:

- graph.facebook.com/**place**/tagged/. This doesn't seem to return recent results.
- graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&center=**coordinates**&distance=200. This only returns results related to a user (and users friends).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

if you just need photos from a specific place I would use instagram instead.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will never be so generous to give all public images to a query. That is like Terabytes of data which can be accessed by anyone with a line of code.

What you can do is get the images of the user and users friends. If its a public app, the user base should grow and you get exposure to more images.

Hope that helps.